# Fast "local" search from a center point or bounding box

Tags: search, heroku, search-engine, elasticsearch

Building a local business directory. Using [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) as our search provider and have a bit of dilemma:

What we really want to do is a "center point" search. But as I understand it, a true "center point" search is significantly slower than a "bounding box" search. So instead we are using a "bounding box" search around a general area that the user is searching. This works great for searches like "tacos" because there are always many results for this search.  The bounding box search does not work well for searches using less common keywords or on searches for specific businesses that are in the area, but lie outside of the bounding box.

A few solutions that I've considered, but I'm not sure if any are any good:

- Do multiple "bounding box" searches, the first of which uses a smaller bounding box, if none or very few results are found, do another search with a larger bounding box.
- Use a "center point" search instead even though it is slower. This search should return results roughly in order of geographical distance from the center point (in combination with other ways that elastic search "prioritizes" results.

I see that websites like [Yelp.com](http://www.yelp.com) seem to have this problem handled. I'm just not sure what is the best way to go about it.

We are running Django on Heroku servers. Out elastic search provider is [Found](https://saas.found.no/).

Your input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you run some benchmarks on your own data, comparing both approaches? Maybe the performance is acceptable or even neglible in your situation?